# Implementing business and other logic in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

(This is my first SwiftUI project; please be kind if this is a stupid question.)

I have a collection of objects which are displayed in a Picker. The picker selection is $selectedIndex, where

```
@State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
```

I also have a

```
@State private var opts: OptsStruct = OptsStruct()
```

where elements of the OptsStruct structure are bound to SwiftUI views. The value of opts needs to change when the selectedIndex changes, because the opts property is the option shown in and selected by the Picker. (Also, I want to save the current value of selectedIndex in UserDefaults.) The problem is that I don't understand how to express these actions in SwiftUI.

I tried

```
@State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0 {
    mutating didSet {
        // save selectedIndex to UserDefaults
        opts = f(selectedIndex)
    }
```

but this causes a Segmentation Fault.

Where is the 'correct' place to put this logic. (And in general, can someone suggest some reading on how to connect changes to SwiftUI @States with general business logic.)

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a `@State` variable is for it to be the single source of truth ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)). This means that one variable should be the only thing that contains the "state" of your picker. In this case, I suggest using this:

```swift
$opts.selectionIndex
```

as the `Binding` for your picker. `selectionIndex` would then be a `Int` property of your `OptsStruct` type.

Comment: I think I was unclear in my original post, because this doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that selectionIndex is changed (by the Picker), a whole new opts struct needs to be changed. While selectionIndex is the source of truth for the Picker in the UI, the opts struct is the source of truth for the rest of the UI. Basically, the Picker is choosing **which** opts struct will be used for the rest of the UI (selecting from an array of possibili

Comment: @user3376086 maybe try making `OptsStruct` a computed property? It seems to me like you still don't have a single source of truth, but I'm not sure how to help you get it down to one.